# pyspark not available in python 27

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Thanks for your help as always.
I have below version of spark and python on my system

```
Spark =: spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
Python := Python27
```

I am running jupyter notebook and while i am executing below command it is showing "modulenotfounderror no module named 'pyspark'"

code is as below :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr,col,column

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

#df = spark.read.csv("C:\Spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\Sample_Test_Data\EMPLOYEES.csv",header=True,sep=",");

#df.filter(col("SALARY")>17000).show(3)

PATH VARIABLE WHICH I HAVE SET ON MY MACHINE IS 

PATH 

C:\Python27;C:\Spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin

PYSPARK_PYTHON

C:\Python27 -->Phyton is installed here 

SPARK_HOME

C:\Spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
```

Note : I have `Python 37` also installed on my system but i can't use it with `Spark 2.1` version thats why i am using `Phyton 27` version.

Please if you know something about let me know.

Thanking you
Anurag Chaudhary

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Python2 is EOL. Please upgrade

Answer (score 0):

> Spark =: spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Looks like you have some code that says `C:\Spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7`??

---

Also, in Spark (2.1.0) docs

> Spark runs on Java 7+, **Python 2.6+/3.4+**

so I suspect Python3.7 works fine...

---

In any case, Python modules have nothing to do with your PATH variable.

You can `pip install pyspark` or use [findspark](https://github.com/minrk/findspark)